# How do I pass variables back out to the calling method in my contoller

Tags: api, model-view-controller, controller

I have a one page MVC web application with just a textbox and search button. Ultimately I am trying to retrieve a list of videos the youtube API finds based on the string value the user searches.

Once the search button is clicked it calls the DisplayVideos method in the Home Controller. The value of the string typed in the textbox is passed into this method which calls another method called RunYouTube which has the code for the API finding the list of videos.

I have a model called YouTubeVideo which contains 2 string properties, one for the video ID and one for the VideoTItle.

I am able to get a video's ID and Title but i am wondering how i get this information (either ytv1 or ytv.ID + ytv.VideoTitle) out of the RunYouTube method and back into the HomeController so that i can display the information on the view.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayVideos(string SearchValue)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            YouTubeVideo ytv = new YouTubeVideo();
            SearchYoutube searchObject = new SearchYoutube();
            await searchObject.RunYouTube(SearchValue);

        }

        return View("Index");
    }


public class SearchYoutube
{
    IList<YouTubeVideo> ytvl = new List<YouTubeVideo>();
    YouTubeVideo ytv = new YouTubeVideo();
    public async Task RunYouTube(string searchword)
    {
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "AIzaSyCa5sqGxd-wpYHH3m_TN73WxJNOcm8AHfs",
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = searchword; 
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

        // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        List<string> videos = new List<string>();
        List<string> channels = new List<string>();
        List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

        // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
        // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
        foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
            {
                case "youtube#video":
                    videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));

                    ytv.Id = searchResult.Id.VideoId;
                    ytv.VideoTitle = searchResult.Snippet.Title;
                    ytvl.Add(ytv);

                    break;



                    //case "youtube#channel":
                    //    channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                    //    break;

                    //case "youtube#playlist":
                    //    playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                    //    break;
            }
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
       // Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
    }
}
```

[image: home controller]

[image: model]

Answer (score 0):

> how i get this information (either ytv1 or ytv.ID + ytv.VideoTitle) out of the RunYouTube method and back into the HomeController so that i can display the information on the view.

You [return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return) it:

```
public async Task<IList<YouTubeVideo>> RunYouTube(string searchword)
{
  ...
  return ytv1;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayVideos(string SearchValue)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ...
    var ytv1 = await searchObject.RunYouTube(SearchValue);
  }

  return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Since 'SearchYoutube.RunYouTube(string)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'?

Comment: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

Comment: @Kalvinl8: See my code again. The return type is `Task<IList<YouTubeVideo>>`.